# How do I make a game controller an active input device on my Mac-mini?

Tags: hardware, mac

How do I make a game controller an active input device on my Mac-mini?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what game controller, and what sort of input that controller offers?

Comment: Yeah, it's a Logitech Dual Action Gamepad, if that helps any (http://www.amazon.com/Apple-Only-Gamepad-Dual-Action/dp/B00171376K/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&qid=1289119568&sr=1-1).  As far as what input it offers, I am just looking to use it as a standard controller.  I am trying to use it with the Snex9x simulator; with that application, you can choose multiple different input devices, but my controller doesn't show up as an option; I thought maybe I needed to make it active in the MAC controls.  I tried checking for that option under the system preferences, but found no options.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, that should read Snes9x simulator ^^.  And, really, thanks for your attention.

Comment: Does it show up in any other apps (ie is in a Snex9x issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Playstation 3 controller, your Mac can recognize it as a bluetooth device and if you pair it with your computer you can set it up to be used as a game controller for your Mac.

I have only tried it with SNES9x, and it DOES work with that app. Playing Super Street Fighter with a wireless PS3 remote is pretty bad ass, I must say, haha.

Not sure what else it would work with, but I am sure you could map the buttons and set it up to work with other games and services once you pair it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it might be an Snes9x issue; I had thought to try the controller with other programs (in part to see if it would work, in part just to play with it), but I hadn't downloaded any games for my NES simulator yet (Nestopia), and I couldn't get Steam to load (I'm not a gamer at all (any case anybody couldn't tell by my asking about simulators for old Nintendo consoles), but my sister had bought me a cheap game on Steam, though I hadn't played it much).  Just now, after Mark's reply, I decided to download a game for Nestopia, and when I checked its options I see it has a link to an emulator enhancer that allows it to work with controllers.  That same site had its own SNES simulator (the BSNES), so I downloaded that one, and my controller now works with both.  So, that's cool.  Thanks for your help, guys.

Comment: @David glad to hear you found a solution. Don’t forget to mark the correct answer :)